# How to separate text data in pandas data frame in a function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

The user inputs the following in a function:

```
 250
 1/3/2012 16:00:00   Missing_1
 1/4/2012 16:00:00   27.47
 1/5/2012 16:00:00   27.728
 1/6/2012 16:00:00   28.19
 1/9/2012 16:00:00   28.1
 1/10/2012 16:00:00  28.15
 12/13/2012 16:00:00 27.52
 12/14/2012 16:00:00 Missing_2
 12/17/2012 16:00:00 27.215
 12/18/2012 16:00:00 27.63
 12/19/2012 16:00:00 27.73
 12/20/2012 16:00:00 Missing_3
 12/21/2012 16:00:00 27.49
 12/24/2012 13:00:00 27.25
 12/26/2012 16:00:00 27.2
 12/27/2012 16:00:00 27.09
 12/28/2012 16:00:00 26.9
 12/31/2012 16:00:00 26.77
```

I am having trouble reading this data and making it a pandas data frame.

I have the following code:

```
def calcMissing(readings):
  import pandas as pd
  df = pd.read_csv(readings, sep =" ") 
  print (df)
```

I am having trouble having it make the data a data frame, and skipping the first line (the value 250) somehow and storing that line somewhere else.

I am expecting a data frame to have two columns, the date column and values column

Comment: did you mean skip rows=1? Also, I tried that and for some reason it makes it only one column

Comment: Oh you're right I guess it is `skiprows=1` or `skiprows=[0]`. @Jess12. It's probably turning the times into the index? Not entirely sure what output you expect.

Comment: Your right I did not make the output very clear, I made an edit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
import pandas as pd
fileName = "file.txt"
dataFrame = pd.read_csv(fileName, sep=" ", skipinitialspace=True, names=['date','time','value'])

df_new = pd.DataFrame()
df_new['timestamp'] = dataFrame['date'].str.cat(dataFrame['time'], sep=" ")
df_new['value'] = dataFrame['value']
dataFrame = df_new
print(dataFrame)
```

Comment: Does not work, `df = pd.read_csv("txt file.txt", sep ='\t', skiprows=1)` does though

Comment: I have added new code as per the modified question.

Comment: You can also add `skiprows=1` to skip first row

Comment: Please consider voting up the answer if it helped !